# How to get info about game purchases from Google Play on server

Tags: google-play

Situation is:

- we sell our games through Google Play;
- we have our own statistics service which counts income and all other financial metrics (it's server application);
- we used google checkout API in this service to get information about game purchases from Google Play (income in particular);
- after google checkout API was dismissed we couldn't find a way where get this information from.

The question now is: how to get information about game purchases from Google Play? I mean not only in-apps but also purchases of premium games.

Answer (score 1):

Note, you can process the CSV monthly transaction report files from the "Financial Reports" tab  using this tool (they have filenames like PlayApps_201401.csv):

https://github.com/eggheadgames/app_earnings

*Full disclosure: my company wrote and open sourced this tool after much searching for something similar. Hope it's useful to others! (It works with Amazon Android app store reports too).*

Answer (score 0):

I've found it myself. There is no notifications mechanism in Google Play now. But you can get game purchase information by downloading financial reports from Google Console. There are reports, which contain transactions (not agregated) info, including financial stats. This reports can be downloaded automaticaly from Google Cloud Storage. See "Financial Reports" tab at Developer Console for details.